# Add value of Option text input to price

Tags: php, ajax, opencart

I'm trying to get the value of a text input Option and add it to the price.

Price is for example $1. The customer input 5 on the text field. The price should now be $6. How can I accomplish this?

Here's the code That I'm working on.

```
$.ajax({

    url: 'index.php?route=product/product/add',

    type: 'post',

    data: $('.product-info input[type=\'text\'], .product-info input[type=\'hidden\'], .product-info input[type=\'radio\']:checked, .product-info input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, .product-info select, .product-info textarea'),

    dataType: 'json',

    success: function(json) {

        $('.success, .warning, .attention, information, .error').remove();

        if (json['error']) {

            if (json['error']['option']) {

                for (i in json['error']['option']) {

                    $('#option-' + i).after('<span class="error">' + json['error']['option'][i] + '</span>');

                }

            }

        } 

        if (json['success']) {

            $('.opprice').html ('<?php echo $text_oprice; ?>' + json['total']);

                            $('.price-tax').html ('Ex Tax: ' + json['tax']);

                                          }

    }

});
```

In this part of the code:

```
data: $('.product-info input[type=\'text\'], .product-info input[type=\'hidden\'], .product-info input[type=\'radio\']:checked, .product-info input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, .product-info select, .product-info textarea'),
```

I tried doing something like this.

```
.product-info input[type=\'text\'].val()
```

But it didn't add up to the price. How can I get the value of the text input and add it to the price?

Comment: Tip: http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/

Comment: try calling the inputs via name as opposed to type: `var price = .product-info input[name=\'price\'].val();`

Comment: Solved already? i have the same problem..